# React: Button does not work (onClick) - should be passed to index.js but nothing happens

Tags: reactjs, button

I have written the following website: https://konekto-571cnq6xu.now.sh/emergency_details1 
If you quickly click through the onboarding and settings, you can see that I have one "Who do you want to contact?" screen. However, if you press the Arrowforward button at the bottom nothing happens and you do not get redirected, even though the handleDetails2() function should take care of it. Here you can see the class concerning that (FormEmergencyType):

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconButton, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import ArrowForward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CheckBoxGroup from '../utils/CheckBoxGroup';
import CheckBox from '../utils/CheckBox';
//import SOSButton from './SOSButton';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    // background: 'white',
    border: 'black',
    'border-width': 'medium',
    'margin-top': '80px',
    background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    'border-radius': '20px'
  },
  item: {
    // background: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    //background: 'white',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'margin-top': '10px'
  },
  label: {
    // background: 'white'
  }
  // forwardbutton: {
  //   'text-align': 'right'
  // }
});

class FormEmergencyType extends React.Component {
  //const classes = useStyles(); //React HOOK API => looks nice
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //const { classes } = props;
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {
      ambulance: props.emergencyTypes.ambulance,
      fire_service: props.emergencyTypes.fire_service,
      car_service: props.emergencyTypes.car_service,
      police: props.emergencyTypes.police,
      emergency_contacts: props.emergencyTypes.emergency_contacts
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, checked) {
    let new_state = this.state;

    switch (event.target.value) {
      case 'ambulance':
        new_state['ambulance'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'fire_service':
        new_state['fire_service'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'police':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['police'] = checked;
        new_state['police'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'car_service':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['car_service'] = checked;
        new_state['car_service'] = checked;
        break;
      case 'emergency_contacts':
        // new_state['emergencytype']['car_service'] = checked;
        new_state['emergency_contacts'] = checked;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    this.setState(new_state);
    this.props.handleEmergencyType(new_state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        className={this.classes.container}
        direction="column"
        spacing={2}
      >
        <Grid item sm={12} className={this.classes.item}>
          <Typography variant="h5">Who do you want to contact?</Typography>
          <CheckBoxGroup>
            <CheckBox
              title="Ambulance"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['ambulance']}
              value="ambulance"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Fire Service"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['fire_service']}
              value="fire_service"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Police"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['police']}
              value="police"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Car Service"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['car_service']}
              value="car_service"
            />
            <CheckBox
              title="Emergency Contacts"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              checked={this.state['emergency_contacts']}
              value="emergency_contacts"
            />
          </CheckBoxGroup>
          <Grid />
          <Grid
            item
            sm={12}
            className={(this.classes.item, this.classes.forwardbutton)}
          >
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              // className={classes.forwardbutton}
              color="black"
              onClick={this.props.handleDetails2}
            >
              <ArrowForward />
            </IconButton>
            {/* <HorizontalNonLinearStepWithError />*/}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(FormEmergencyType);
```

This might be associated with the Settings file but I have no idea what might be the reason. Here you can see the index.js file which calls the FormEmergencyType.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Header } from '../Layout';
import FormPersonType from './FormPersonType';
import FormEmergencyType from './FormEmergencyType';
import AppContext from '../utils/AppContext';
import CONST from '../utils/Constants';

class SOS extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      componentType: 'type_of_person',
      ambulance: false,
      fire_service: false,
      police: false,
      car_service: false,
      meAffected: false,
      anotherPerson: false
    };

    this.handleComponentType = this.handleComponentType.bind(this);
    this.handleEmergencyType = this.handleEmergencyType.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  showSettings(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleComponentType(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({ componentType: 'type_of_emergency' });
  }

  handleEmergencyType(new_emergency_state) {
    console.log(new_emergency_state);
    this.setState(new_emergency_state);
  }

  handleDetails2() {
    this.props.history.push('/emergency_details2');
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    console.log('in OnSubmit');
    axios
      .post(CONST.URL + 'emergency/create', {
        id: 1,
        data: this.state
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let component;

    if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_person') {
      component = (
        <FormPersonType
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          personTypes={this.state}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.componentType === 'type_of_emergency') {
      component = (
        <FormEmergencyType
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          handleEmergencyType={this.handleEmergencyType}
          handleDetails2={this.handleDetails2}
          emergencyTypes={this.state}
          timerStart={this.timerStart}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header title="Send out SOS" />
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
          {component}
        </Container>
        {/*component = (
        <HorizontalNonLinearStepWithError
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
        />*/}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

export default withRouter(SOS);

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn't bind your `handleDetails2` function, in console you have this error when clicking the last arrow :

```
react-dom.production.min.js:232 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at value (index.js:47)
```

Just bind it like you did for the other functions in your `constructor`

```
this.handleDetails2 = this.handleDetails2.bind(this)
```

or make it an arrow function

```
handleDetails2 = () => this.props.history.push('/emergency_details2');
```